# Can we test Face ID in simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, biometrics, iphone-x, face-id

Can we test biometric authentication using the simulator?

The iPhone X Simulator shows a menu for Face ID enrollment, but after enabling that, what can I do?

How it will recognize a face for authentication?

[image: iPhone X Simulator - Face ID settings]

Comment: In later versions you find "Face ID" here : Simulator > Features > Face ID

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Simulator does not recognise a face but allows you to simulate a matching and non-matching faces, if you've enabled `Enrolled` option from `Face ID`.

---

Add following code to your view controller and try with Face-ID

```
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        localAuthentication()
    }



    func localAuthentication() -> Void {

        let laContext = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
        let biometricsPolicy = LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

        if (laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, error: &error)) {

            if let laError = error {
                print("laError - \(laError)")
                return
            }

            var localizedReason = "Unlock device"
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.faceID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Face ID"
                    print("FaceId support")
                } else if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.touchID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Touch ID"
                    print("TouchId support")
                } else {
                    print("No Biometric support")
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }


            laContext.evaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, localizedReason: localizedReason, reply: { (isSuccess, error) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    if let laError = error {
                        print("laError - \(laError)")
                    } else {
                        if isSuccess {
                            print("sucess")
                        } else {
                            print("failure")
                        }
                    }

                })
            })
        }


    }
}
```

---

**FaceID authentication will prompt you for first time to allow FaceID detection for your app.**

[image]

---

Now enable Face ID enrolment and run your app to test Face ID simulation Testing.

**Here is simulation result for matching and non-matching faces.**

**Result for matching face:**

[image]

**Result for non-matching face:**

[image]

---

Comment: Can one somehow customize that square Face ID prompt?
I'd like to add some text there. Is it possible?

Comment: @AndreySolovyov It's not customizable.

Answer (score 9):

The simulator just simulates the outcome of a correct and a failed face recognition, just like it does with Touch ID. It **does not recognize faces**.

Comment: Thanks, got your point. I am working with biometric first time. So we have to press match face during authentication to authenticate successfully.

Answer (score 1):

See this article.  You can create the Biometrics.m,  Biometrics.h, and bridging-header.h files within you UITests folder and update your UI test target to use that bridging header.
https://github.com/KaneCheshire/BiometricAutomationDemo

Answer (score 0):

As you asking - *but after enabling that, what can I do?*

Just like a touch Id enrolment, You can verify things with face-Id on iPhone-X.
However simulator have some limitations like Appstore etc.
With face-Id enrolment you can do following things -

- Use Face ID to make purchases.
- Sign in with Face ID (Sign in to apps).
- Autofill passwords in Safari.
- In the iTunes Store, App Store, and iBooks Store.

[See more at Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208109)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will surely check links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

same as give by @krunal just 2nd if should be outside of 1st.

```
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    localAuthentication()
}

func localAuthentication() -> Void {

    let laContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    let biometricsPolicy = LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

    if (laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, error: &error)) {



        var localizedReason = "Unlock device"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.faceID) {
                localizedReason = "Unlock using Face ID"
                print("FaceId support")
            } else if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.touchID) {
                localizedReason = "Unlock using Touch ID"
                print("TouchId support")
            } else {
                print("No Biometric support")
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


        laContext.evaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, localizedReason: localizedReason, reply: { (isSuccess, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let laError = error {
                    print("laError - \(laError)")
                } else {
                    if isSuccess {
                        print("sucess")
                    } else {
                        print("failure")
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
//This should be outside of if

 if let laError = error {
        print("laError - \(laError)")
        return
     }
 }
}
```