# Is this correct to check FaceID?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, iphone-x, face-id

> Sorry, unavailability of iPhone-X.

After the launch of iPhone-X, everyone wants their application should be compatible with iOS11 and with touchID but the problem is it's too expensive for a developer to test touch ID.

I don't have iPhone to check my code but can I check the same in iOS simulator?

```
let context = LAContext()
if ( context.biometryType == .typeFaceID ) {
      // Face ID
}
if ( context.biometryType == .typeTouchID) {
     // Touch ID
} else {
    // Stone Age
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159066/can-we-test-face-id-in-simulator/47160418#47160418)

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanku @kerberos

Answer (score 11):

You can test it without device also. Use simulator's Face ID to validate your code and it will behave similarly in iPhone-X also.

Simulator does not recognise a face but allows you to simulate a matching and non-matching faces, if you've enabled `Enrolled` option from `Face ID`.

Add following code to your view controller and try with Face-ID

```
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        localAuthentication()
    }



    func localAuthentication() -> Void {

        let laContext = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
        let biometricsPolicy = LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

        if (laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, error: &error)) {

            if let laError = error {
                print("laError - \(laError)")
                return
            }

            var localizedReason = "Unlock device"
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.faceID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Face ID"
                    print("FaceId support")
                } else if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.touchID) {
                    localizedReason = "Unlock using Touch ID"
                    print("TouchId support")
                } else {
                    print("No Biometric support")
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }


            laContext.evaluatePolicy(biometricsPolicy, localizedReason: localizedReason, reply: { (isSuccess, error) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    if let laError = error {
                        print("laError - \(laError)")
                    } else {
                        if isSuccess {
                            print("sucess")
                        } else {
                            print("failure")
                        }
                    }

                })
            })
        }


    }
}
```

**FaceID authentication will prompt you for first time to allow FaceID detection for your app.**

[image]

Now enable Face ID enrolment and run your app to test Face ID simulation Testing.

**Here is simulation result for matching and non-matching faces.**

**Result for matching face:**

[image]

**Result for non-matching face:**

[image]

Comment: Good answer. A key bit that's easily lost in all this code — the `biometryType` property has nothing to do with *implementing* Face ID support. Checking enrollment and authenticating are the same `canEvaluatePolicy` and `evaluatePolicy` calls you use for Touch ID. Use `biometryType` not as part of your authentication logic, but to tell users what kind of authentication is in use. (Think of all the bank apps that give you a "use Touch ID" checkbox after your first login — they need to know to say "Face ID" instead.)

Comment: @rickster you are welcomed to edit and improve this answer. Please share your inputs by editing this answer.