# How to check Face id is enabled for my application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x, face-id

I have implemented face id API in my application. Currently Face id is registered for device but disabled for my app.

How do I check programmatically in Swift that Face id is enabled for my app?

I know to check the face id is registered in device or not.

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47182769/309046

Comment: @RohitKale - did you find a way to check whether in the settings page of iPhone, the Face ID / Touch ID toggle is on/off for the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let context = LAContext()
if ( context.biometryType == .typeFaceID ) {
      // Face ID
}
if ( context.biometryType == .typeTouchID) {
     // Touch ID
} else {
    // Stone Age
}
```

don't forgot to put versioning condition cuz faceID is only available after ios 11