# How to reenable FaceID on iPhone X simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, settings, simulator, iphone-x, face-id

Not a duplicate of [Can we test FaceID in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159066/can-we-test-face-id-in-simulator).

It appears [in this article](https://www.iphonelife.com/content/how-to-turn-face-id-apps-settings-iphone-x), that the ability to update FaceID settings for a specific app is possible, however this does not seem to be the case in the iPhone X simulator (xCode version: 9.2).

The only other setting that appears in the same sub-list as the "General" category is "Privacy", and it does not appear to be under the app's settings.

Ultimately, I am trying to test a workflow for when the user is attempting to re-enable FaceID for my react-native app, once they've left and come back.

Does anyone know how to enable to FaceID settings in the simulator's settings, or change the preferences while the app is still installed and backgrounded on the device?