# LAContext().biometryType returns .none on iPhone X

Tags: ios, localauthentication, core-authentication

I'm facing a problem with `CoreAuthentication`.

I have called `canEvaluatePolicy:error:` as the documentation ask for but the result is always `.none`.

```
fileprivate let biometricsType: SecurityBiometrics = {
        var error: NSError?
        let evaluated = LAContext().canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if LAContext().biometryType == .faceID { return .faceID }
            if LAContext().biometryType == .touchID { return .touchID }
        } else {
            if (evaluated || (error?.code != LAError.touchIDNotAvailable.rawValue)) {
                return .touchID
            }
        }
        return .none
    }()

// biometricsType returns `.none`
```

A error is showing up on the console :

> [LAClient] initWithExistingContext -> (null), Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this
>   process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this
>   process.}

It already have worked before, but now (without any changes) it's still returning `.none`.

Do you have run into the same error ?

Comment: [How to test face-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159066/can-we-test-face-id-in-simulator/47160418#47160418) - Here is complete working code. You can get your requirement relevant code .

Comment: @Krunal `The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this process.` is now displayed twice on the console but it's now working. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't share full error message. Here is full error message:

> [LAClient] initWithExistingContext -> (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this process.}
>   2018-03-29 13:42:37.866753+0530 Test[1505:35036] [LAClient] initWithExistingContext -> (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated from this process.}

In normal language, it says you have a problem with `LAContext()` which is initialised every time (`[LAClient] initWithExistingContext -> (null)`) in your code block. Use a single instance of LAContext.

Try this and see:

```
fileprivate let biometricsType: LABiometryType = {
    let laContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    let evaluated = laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)

    if let laError = error {
        print("laError - \(laError)")
        return .none
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if laContext.biometryType == .faceID { return .faceID }
        if laContext.biometryType == .touchID { return .touchID }
    } else {
        if (evaluated || (error?.code != LAError.touchIDNotAvailable.rawValue)) {
            return .touchID
        }
    }
    return .none
}()

// print biometricsType
print("biometricsType - \(biometricsType.rawValue)")
```

Result: biometricsType - 2

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought about the single instance.. My bad !